# Need help creating Cron to download XML file daily

Tags: php, xml, curl, cron, wget

I would like to create a cron job to download an xml file daily at midnight.
I want to overwrite any pre-existing file as well.

I tried

```
1 0 *** usr/bin/wget  http://ace-tv.xyz:25461/xmltv.php?username=xxxx&password=xxxx --output-file=/home/username/myxmlfile.xml
```

I get a 200 ok for connecting...but nothing downloads.

I think the problem has something to do with the request coming from a php server and I'm not familiar with wget or curl enough to figure it out.

If I paste the URL into a browser the xml schema shows up and I can right click and do "save as" but I need this done by cron.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need spaces between the `*` characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose there is "--output-document=.." option:

```
1 0 *** usr/bin/wget --output-document=/home/username/myxmlfile.xml "http://ace-tv.xyz:25461/xmltv.php?username=xxxx&password=xxxx"
```

Also please note that you need to use URL string in quotes if it contains characters like "&"

Comment: I had tried the <code>--output-document=</code> earlier, but I guess the quotes is where I got lost.

Thanks! Works great now!